# Loading previous saved variables into DynamicModule

Tags: import, dynamic, gui-construction

I have a GUI, built inside a DynamicModule.
I would like to be able to load previous set options and values, changing the values that are currently set within the DynamicModule, not the global variables.

For instance, make a file containing 4 variables:

```
a = True; b = False; c = True; d = 100;
Save["test.mdx", {a, b, c, d}]
Clear[a, b, c, d]
```

Now I have a little Dynamic with a button, but the `Get` will load the variables into the general context. Is there a way to get it to replace the values within the DynamicModule?

```
DynamicModule[{a = False, b = True, c = False, d = 1},
 Row[{Checkbox[Dynamic[a]], Checkbox[Dynamic[b]], 
   Checkbox[Dynamic[c]], Spacer[10], Dynamic[d], 
   Button["Get Data", Get["test.mdx"]]}]
 ]
```

Other methods of locally importing a number of variables from a previous run are welcome. The number of saved variables may change, and won't be everything in the `DynamicModule` scope.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86122/discussion-on-question-by-krazug-loading-previous-saved-variables-into-dynamicmo).